# VBA function causing runtime error 13 while returning array in excel 2016 but not in office 365?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that reads data in an tab and returns it as an 1D array:

```
Public Function OneDimension(arr)
    OneDimension = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(arr))
End Function
```

the function is called when the form is opened:

```
Set actionDict = New Scripting.Dictionary
numArrCols = Data.Columns.Count - 1
ReDim arr(1 To numArrCols) 'empty array

For Each rw In Data.rows
    id = "" & rw.Cells(1).Value
    If Not actionDict.Exists(id) Then
        actionDict.Add id, New Collection 'new key: add key and empty collection
    End If
    actionDict(id).Add OneDimension(rw.Cells(2).Resize(1, numArrCols).Value) 'add the row value as 1D array
Next rw
```

The data looks like this:

| user id | name | date | answer | amount | comments | completed | helper |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test,t | 05/22/2022 | yes | 0.01 | something | No | 144687 |

with the formula

```
helper = user id & date
```

`user id` is a text field, and `date` is stored as `mm/dd/yyyy`, when I run it with Office 365 it seems fine, but when my boss ran it with excel 2016 it gave this error:

```
runtime error 13 type mismatch
```

with this in the debugger:

[image: debugger error]

What could be causing this?

Comment: [Transpose limitation in older Excel versions](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/limitations-of-transpose-in-vba.442358/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### One-Row Range to 1D Array

- Why use one-liners with limited functionality? They are shorter but usually not faster.
- In your sub, you could use:

  ```
  actionDict(id).Add OneDaRow(rw.Cells(2).Resize(1, numArrCols))
  ```

**The Function**

```vb
Function OneDaRow(ByVal RowRange As Range) As Variant
    
    Dim Data As Variant ' 2D one-based one-row array
    Dim c As Long
    
    With RowRange.Rows(1)
        c = .Columns.Count
        If c = 1 Then ' one cell
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = .Value
        Else ' multiple cells
            Data = .Value
        End If
    End With
        
    Dim Arr As Variant: ReDim Arr(1 To c) ' 1D one-based array
    
    For c = 1 To c
        Arr(c) = Data(1, c)
    Next c
    
    OneDaRow = Arr

End Function
```

**A Function Test**

```vb
Sub OneDaRowTEST()
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Debug.Print Join(OneDaRow(rg), vbLf)
End Sub
```